# Is it generally accepted to ask a newbie question on a distro's mailing-list?

Tags: debian

In my quest for security related knowledge on a more specific StackExchange site, [someone pointed me towards the more general Debian mailing lists](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/55548/newer-raspbian-package-installed-than-made-available-by-debian-prev-how-do-ras#comment84429_55548) (as my chances for answers would be probably better there).

However I am fairly intimidated by the topics and the deep conversations on there. I have already subscribed and will first search the existing archive naturally.. but I think I'll end up having to ask my question there, in the end. So hence my - more general - normative question here:

- Is it generally accepted to ask a newbie question on a distro's mailing-list (of course after having tried to search the web / read-up as much as possible)?

I found (just discovered) StackEchange to have a low barrier of entry (as long as one respects the basic rules / uses common sense). But I'm not sure whether dedicated old-school mailing list followers are as kind as the people on here..

Comment: This question belongs in http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How-come? This (more general) question about the Linux community has nothing to do with Raspberry PI (the original question did, but this follow-up does not,or am I mistaking here)? I *would* have asked on a Debian StackExchange (as it regards this specific case), but that one does not exist, and - to be frank - this question could regard any distro's mailing-list afaiac.

Comment: Sorry, I originally misread your question as asking if it was acceptable to redirect newbie's questions to the distro's mailing list -- which would be an etiquette question for the particular exchange's meta exchange.

Comment: This is *so* close to belonging on Meta, but it's good here too :)

Comment: @Jesusaurus - No worries we are all benefiting from clean StackExhange channels! And, as Cat also pointed out, it *is* very close to a meta question, so I can imagine you perceiving it as such on a first glance! Thanks for helping the community!

Comment: Welcome to the site! I closed your question as too broad since there simply isn't a single answer to this, it will depend on the culture of the specific mailing list you choose to use. Therefore, we can't really answer. The answer you got from Stephen (who's a Debian developer, by the way, so he should know) is answering a different question: "What *Debian* mailing list should I use for newbie questions" which is a good deal more specific. By the way, note that you could probably just ask your question directly here instead of on the mailing list.

Comment: @terdon - Thanks for pointing me into the right direction by elaborately pointing out why this question should be closed (incl. examples)! I'm still trying to get my bearings (although answers to this question *did* provide me with the info I needed). I got both redirected for being too specific ([servervault > information-security](https://serverfault.com/posts/799023/revisions)), and for being too broad (this one). I'll learn to better balance in time! For now I'll follow-up on Stephen's advice and ask any Debian-user specific questions (that are worth it) on the corresponding mailing list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Debian has a number of [user-oriented mailing lists](https://lists.debian.org/users.html); the most general one is [`debian-user`](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/) which is described as "Community assistance and support for Debian users". This list is most definitely open to newbies, and newbie questions are welcome there!

Comment: Thanks! That indeed seems like a reasonable place to start (I subscribed to "security", but for my initiating question - as posted here - most perfectly fits the debian-user one)! Marked as answered!

Answer (score 3):

> Is it generally accepted to ask a newbie question on a distro's
>   mailing-list (of course after having tried to search the web / read-up
>   as much as possible)?

Ask on the mailing lists.

Comment: [Hmm, not sure If you are deliberately using circular reasoning](http://www.troll.me/images/futurama-fry/i-see-what-you-did-there.jpg); or that you are stating that I *should* actually feel free ask on there.

Comment: P.S. It was not me who down-voted your answer.

Comment: Of course I mean you should feel free to ask. And ask THEM not people here, though there's a chance some people from there visit this site. Your question will be helpful to other people with your concerns.

Answer (score 3):

The thing to remember about mailing lists is that they send emails to everyone on this list. You need to think of your intended audience for your question.

Yes it is generally acceptable to send "noob questions" to a mailing list, but unlike SE or forums, you "force" your question on everyone (as apposed to only people that find it interesting).

A good rule of thumb, is: "Would you stand up in the middle of a conference and ask for eveyone's attention, then ask your question?"

Now, I know that is intimidating, but again, the core difference form a mailing list an a forum, is that the mailing list actually mails everyone on the list, grabs their attention, and then gives them your posting.

Now, there are certainly mailing lists that are more "noob" friendly then others. Usually they are -support or -users mailing lists.

Also keep in mind that people join those mailing lists to help. So don't be afraid to ask for that help. Your best bet is to join the mailing list, see the kind of traffic it generates, and figure out what to do from there. If your question seems "on the level" with the other questions and discussion topics then go for it. If you feel like everyone it talking way over your head, maybe look for a different mailing list. Most of them are friendly and will at least point you in the right direction.

DO NOT FORGET ETIQUETTE

For example see https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/MailingListEtiquette

Most lists will have something like that posted somewhere. Stick to it. Remember your contact 50,000 people directly. Not a good time to be rude.

Comment: Noted! Very good advice (I especially like the conference analogy)! I'll come up with a post that respects everyone's time and effort on the mailing-list in the weekend (more time to refine rethink do some more research).